# don't want to rotate the image in carousel while rotating carousel

Tags: iphone, rotation, carousel

I am using Nick Lockwood carousel and type is Wheel Carousel. I am using the images as items in carousel. The problem is when I rotate the carousel the image also rotates, i.e. consider a person image, then the person image gets tilted, which I don't want, i.e. I don't want to rotate that particular image while rotating whole carousel. Can anyone please help?

Comment: you mean you want that the person's face always remains vertical?

Comment: yes the person's face should remain vertical

Answer (score 5):

Look in the implementation of `- (CATransform3D)transformForItemView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(CGFloat)offset;` Find the `case iCarouselTypeWheel:` and `case iCarouselTypeInvertedWheel:` block.

Change the code that generates the final transforms (for both the vertical and horizontal cases) to reverse the applied rotation:

```
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, radius, 0.0f);
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle * offset, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

// this is the transform the existing code returns...
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, -radius, offset * 0.01f);

// instead you reverse the rotation before returning...
return CATransform3DRotate(transform, -(angle * offset), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This definitely helped! Thanks for posting this :).

Comment: Helped me to, this should be validated.

Comment: @CarltonGibson Hi, can you help me achieving one thing with iCarousel, is I want to add scale animation for the selected item, but it doesn't seems to be working for me, it ignores the animation and appear scaled without animation..

Comment: @iphonic — that sounds a bit complicated for the comments here. Put it in a new question with as much context as you can — it really depends on what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the file iCarousel.m, and find the `- (CATransform3D)transformForItemView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(CGFloat)offset` method; inside of it you will find this block:

```
    case iCarouselTypeWheel:
    case iCarouselTypeInvertedWheel:
    {
        NSInteger count = [self valueForTransformOption:iCarouselTranformOptionCount withDefault:
                           MIN(numberOfVisibleItems, numberOfItems + numberOfPlaceholdersToShow)];

        CGFloat arc = [self valueForTransformOption:iCarouselTranformOptionArc withDefault:M_PI * 2.0f];
        CGFloat radius = [self valueForTransformOption:iCarouselTranformOptionRadius withDefault:itemWidth * (CGFloat)count / arc];
        CGFloat angle = [self valueForTransformOption:iCarouselTranformOptionAngle withDefault:arc / (CGFloat)count];

        if (type == iCarouselTypeInvertedWheel)
        {
            radius = -radius;
            angle = -angle;
        }

        if (vertical)
        {
            transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -radius, 0.0f, 0.0f);
 /* this */     transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle * offset, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, radius, 0.0f, offset * 0.01f);
        }
        else
        {
            transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, radius, 0.0f);
  /* this */    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle * offset, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, -radius, offset * 0.01f);
        }
    }
```

Try simply to comment out the two lines:

```
     transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle * offset, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

and see what happens; I guess that the face will not be rotated, but then you might need to adjust the translation...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am trying for that only but still have not found solution, I am trying and will post if find it, if anyone else have found that then please help

Answer (score 0):

Try conditionally rotating the image depending on the device orientation in the

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view;
```

delegate method.

Comment: I am not rotating device, the carousel only has to rotate but the images within it should remain as they are, their place should only change

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from the above answers I wasn't able to really fix the issue. I reused part of the comments but not the code. What worked for me was this.

```
        if (_vertical)
        {
            transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -radius, 0.0, 0.0);
            transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle * offset, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, radius, 0.0, offset * 0.01);
            return CATransform3DRotate(transform, -(angle * offset), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
        else
        {
            transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0, radius, 0.0);
            transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle * offset, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0, -radius, offset * 0.01);
            return CATransform3DRotate(transform, -(angle * offset), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
```